# Ruby EventMachine with PostgreSQL

Tags: ruby, activerecord, asynchronous, eventmachine, sequel

I know that for mysql [em-mysql](https://github.com/tmm1/em-mysql) exists as an asynchronous interface driver to MySQL and that Active Record, with some modification, can make immediate use of. I believe Sequel has this capability already. I also understand that the pg gem exposes PostgreSQL's native async API.

My question: is there any Ruby ORM that natively interoperates with EventMachine when the backing database is PostgreSQL? If not, what needs to be done to retrofit Sequel to support async PostgreSQL? ActiveRecord?

Comment: You might want to ask on the sequel-talk google group. Or search the archives. There is at least one discussion of this issue [here](http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk/browse_thread/thread/5fb3f5e1c6dcb710)

Comment: Sequel does currently use pg's async API, but only so it doesn't block the interpreter.  I don't believe Sequel currently supports nonblocking frameworks such as EventMachine, and I'm not sure how extensive the changes required to support it would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it works with ActiveRecord:

https://github.com/mperham/em_postgresql